How do I preserve Em and En dashes in Powershell text processing?
I'm doing some text find and replaces in an XML file and I need to preserve the En and Em dash encoding.
I'm importing the text from my file using Get-Content with the Encoding parameter set to UTF8. I'm using search and replaces like the following:
    # SPACED/UNSPACED LONG DASH (4,34)
    $fileContents = $fileContents -replace ' — ', ' – '
    $fileContents = $fileContents -replace '— ', ' – '
    $fileContents = $fileContents -replace ' —', ' – '
    $fileContents = $fileContents -replace '—', ' – '

I want this particular example to find an Em dash and convert it to a spaced En dash.
However, I've tried various output Encoding options when writing back to my file with set-Content but I'm getting some rather strange characters instead of the dashes :-( The nature of my work is such that the En dash must remain an En dash and not be converted to e.g. hyphens or any other character sequences ...
Any idea how I can do this? TIA :-)
WHOLE SCRIPT:
#load the .NET System.Windows.Forms class into our PowerShell session:
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
    
#load the .NET Presentation Framework related libraries
#to allow us to use Message Boxes
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework

#set debug variable - controls output to console:
$DebugPreference = "Continue" # allows o/p to console
#$DebugPreference = "SilentlyContinue" #no o/p to console

$script:myfile = "" #initialise and set scope of $myfile
function UpdateOpenFileLabel($NewFileLabel)
{
    $OpenFileLabel.Text = "File: $NewFileLabel"
}

##################
# EVENT HANDLERS #
##################

#event handler code for if file open button is clicked:
function fileOpenButton_OnClick 
{
    write-debug "IN: fileOpenButton_OnClick"
    $openFileResult = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
    write-debug "Open file: $openFileResult"
    
    if ($openFileResult -eq 'OK')
    {
        #Get the path of specified file
        $script:myfile = $FileBrowser.FileName

        UpdateOpenFileLabel($myfile)
        write-debug "selected file: $myfile"
        write-debug "Saved file name: $myfile"
    }
    else {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('NO FILE SELECTED','User cancelled file open','Ok',0)
        $script:myfile = ""
        write-debug "else: Saved file name: $myfile"
        #display "None" on the form.
        UpdateOpenFileLabel("None")
    }
    
    write-debug "OUT: fileOpenButton_OnClick"
}

#event handler code for if punctuation macro button is clicked:
function runMagSrchMacroButton_OnClick
{
    write-debug "IN: runMagSrchMacroButton_OnClick"
    write-debug "myfile = $myfile"

        #check whether a file has been selected:
    if ($myfile -eq "")
    {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Please select a file', 'NO FILE SELECTED','Ok',0)
    }
    else {
        # file HAS been selected:
#        $fileContents = Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 $myfile
        $fileContents = Get-Content $myfile

        # do text replacements:

        #################################################################
        # Convert all DASHES to spaced short dashes (4,33 or alt-0150). #
        #################################################################
        
        # SHORT DASH: correct spacing to be spaced on both sides (4,33)
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace ' – ', '–'
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace '– ', '–'
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace ' –', '–'
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace '–', ' – '

        # SPACED HYPHEN: 
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace ' - ', ' – '

        # SPACED/UNSPACED LONG DASH (4,34)
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace ' — ', ' – '
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace '— ', ' – '
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace ' —', ' – '
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace '—', ' – '
        
        #############
        # TYPEFORMS #
        #############

        # If PUNCTUATION occurs outside typeform, move it inside.
        #(this search does not include brackets)        
        $fileContents = $fileContents -replace '(</i>|</b>|</u>)([\.,;:!\?])', '$2$1'

        ######################################
        # WRITE EDITED TEXT BACK TO XML FILE #
        ######################################
#        $fileContents | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $myfile
        $fileContents | Set-Content $myfile


        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Dash and punctuation searches completed successfully :-)','Mag Search Macro','Ok',0)
    }
    #DEBUG
    write-debug "OUT: runMagSrchMacroButton_OnClick"
}

#event handler code for if file open button is clicked:
function exitButton_OnClick
{
     #DEBUG
     write-debug "IN: exitButton_OnClick"
    $main_gui.Close()
     #DEBUG
     write-debug "OUT: exitButton_OnClick"
}

##########################
# START OF SCRIPT PROPER #
##########################

#Create form for our GUI:
$main_gui = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_gui.Text = 'Correct punctuation outside typeform'
$main_gui.Width = 450
$main_gui.Height = 200
$main_gui.Autosize = $true #automatically resizes box to fit elements.


####################
# FILE OPEN BUTTON #
####################
#define a button for opening a file:
$fileOpenButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$fileOpenButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,20)
#$fileOpenButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$fileOpenButton.Text = "Select file"
$fileOpenButton.AutoSize = $true

#specify event handler for file open button:
$fileOpenButton.add_Click({fileOpenButton_OnClick})

$main_gui.Controls.Add($fileOpenButton)

#define file browser
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$FileBrowser.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
$FileBrowser.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
#xml file filter indices: 1 = xml files; 2 = All files:
$FileBrowser.FilterIndex = 1 
$FileBrowser.RestoreDirectory = $true

###################
# OPEN FILE LABEL #
###################

$OpenFileLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

if ($myfile -eq "")
{
    #no file selected.
    UpdateOpenFileLabel("None")
}
else
{
    UpdateOpenFileLabel("$myfile")
}


$OpenFileLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200, 20)

$OpenFileLabel.AutoSize = $true

$main_gui.Controls.Add($OpenFileLabel)


###########################
# MAG SEARCH MACRO BUTTON #
###########################
#define a button for running regexp:
$runMagSrchMacroButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$runMagSrchMacroButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,80)
#$fileOpenButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$runMagSrchMacroButton.Text = "Run magazine searches macro"
$runMagSrchMacroButton.AutoSize = $true

#specify event handler for punctuation macro button:
$runMagSrchMacroButton.add_Click({runMagSrchMacroButton_OnClick})

$main_gui.Controls.Add($runMagSrchMacroButton)

###############
# EXIT BUTTON #
###############
#define an app exit button:
$exitButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$exitButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,80)
#$fileOpenButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$exitButton.Text = "Exit"
$exitButton.AutoSize = $true
#specify event handler for exit button:
$exitButton.add_Click({exitButton_OnClick})
$main_gui.Controls.Add($exitButton)


#Set the start position of the form to the center of the screen.
$main_gui.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$main_gui.ShowDialog() #displays the form


I am not aware of any context in which PowerShell would make such substitutions - certainly not in in-memory string replacements. Even when writing to a file with Set-Content in Windows PowerShell it wouldn't happen, at least not if the system's active ANSI code page is Windows-1252, because these characters do exist in that encoding, and PowerShell translates accordingly. With Out-File and - in PowerShell (Core) 7 with any file-writing cmdlet - any character is preserved, due to using a Unicode encoding.

If your active ANSI code page doesn't include these characters, then writing with Set-Content -Encoding utf8 should fix the problem.

Please show the code with which you write it to file - the portion of your code that you've shared here is unlikely to be where the problem is

whole script is now in the question above

Where are you seeing the strange characters? Is it when you open the resulting file in a specific application? And do you see the strange characters in the original file in the same application? Are you able to open the original file in a hex editor and check whether or not the file has a Byte Order Marker (BOM) in the first few bytes?

Hi @mclayton, the file is usually viewed and edited in WordPerfect 9. The original file displays correctly in WP9, showing the corresponding En or Em dash. After the PowerShell script has run, the strange characters have replaced the dashes in both WP9 and also when I view it in WinMerge to compare it with the original (unprocessed) file.

Since you mention strange characters, the problem is likely at the source, i.e. that what you're reading with Get-Content gets misinterpreted. The Get-Content call in your code does not use -Encoding utf8; what happens if you add the latter, also to the Set-Content call?

Could you copy and paste the strange characters into your post. It’s very likely an encoding mismatch issue and it may be possible to work out what the mismatched encodings are based on the exact “strange characters” being displayed.

Hi mclayton and mklement0, when I use -Encoding utf8, I get strange characters. I think @mclayton is correct in saying that the encodings are mismatched - I've just noticed that in Winmerge, the original input file is detected as being plain UTF8 ( no BOM) whereas the output file written to by PowerShell is detected as being  UTF8BOM. When I open the output file in WordPerfect, it detects it as being ASCII and misinterprets the dash characters. If I select "XML UTF8" encoding in WP upon opening the output file, WP crashes and bombs out.

Is there any way of getting PowerShell to write the file without using a BOM? TIA

Can you post the original "strange characters" so we can see what they are.. Any suggestions would be guesswork without seeing them...

Thanks @mklement0 - using New-Item has fixed the problem and now the output from my PowerShell script opens and displays correctly in WP

Glad to hear it, @HelenT; I've written up a proper answer.

@mklement0 You said, "...not if the system's active ANSI code page is Windows-1252, because these characters do exist in that encoding" In fact, en dash (U+2013) and em dash (U+2014) are both supported in cp 1252, represented as 0x96 and 0x97. These are not supported in cp 437, however.

@PeterConstable, yes, that's why I said they do exist and also "PowerShell translates accordingly" (but I didn't spell out the corresponding Windows-1252 code points, which you just did).

The fact that you're seeing what you call strange characters in lieu of the original — (EM DASH, U+2014) characters implies that there is a character-encoding mismatch somewhere, which in turn implies that  a mismatch occurs upon deserializing  and/or serializing byte representations of text (strings), such as when reading and/or writing text from/to files.
In addition to your Get-Content and Set-Content calls, the character encoding of your source code file (*.ps1) can also be affected, if it contains non-ASCII characters such as and – (EN DASH, U+2013), which means that even if the text file to process is read correctly, your -replace operations involving non-ASCII characters will be ineffective if your source-code file is misinterpreted.

To prevent misinterpretation of UTF-8-encoded *.ps1 files by Windows PowerShell, be sure to save them as UTF-8 with BOM. (This is no longer necessary in PowerShell (Core) 7, but the latter understands UTF-8 files with a BOM too.)

In Windows PowerShell, when reading source code or calling Get-Content to read from a file without a BOM, and Set-Content to write a file (without an -Encoding argument), the default is ANSI encoding, i.e. the encoding implied by the active system locale, aka language for non-Unicode programs, e.g. Windows-1252 on US-English systems.[1]
Such an ANSI encoding is typically a fixed, single-byte encoding, where each and every byte represents a character, causing the multi-byte-on demand encoding of non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 to be misinterpreted as multiple (unrelated) characters; e.g., — turns into â€”.[1]

Therefore, when dealing with BOM-less UTF-8 files in Windows PowerShell:

On reading:

Be sure to use -Encoding UTF8, i.e. Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 $myfile in your case.


On writing:

Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 unfortunately does not work, because it invariably creates a UTF-8 file with BOM (the same applies to Out-File -Encoding UTF8).

The simplest workaround is to use New-Item:
New-Item -Force $myfile -Value (($fileContents -join "`r`n") + "`r`n")


See this answer for background information and alternatives.




Note that no extra effort is needed in PowerShell (Core) 7, which consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8, across all cmdlets.
(In the event that you want to write UTF-8 files with BOM, use -Encoding utf8BOM there.)

[1] In Windows 10 and above it is possible to configure a system to use UTF-8 system-wide, in which case both the OEM and the ANSI code page are set to 65001 (UTF-8). However, this has far-reaching consequences in that it can change the behavior of existing console applications and PowerShell scripts; see this answer for details as well as a PowerShell-only alternative.
[2] — (EM DASH), when encoded as UTF-8, comprises 3 bytes, which, when interpreted as individual Windows-1252 characters result in this string. You can verify this as follows: [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString([System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new().GetBytes('—'))
